# ASP If, Else If only evaluates first statement

Tags: asp.net, if-statement

I'm relatively competent with javascript. I thought asp might be as forgiving, but I'm pulling my hair out over this.

I want to determine if the request url has a specific query string in order to run some code. However, (my) ASP seems to fail if the exact string isn't matched:

```
<% If Request.QueryString("somestring") Then%> target="_blank" <% Else If Not Request.QueryString() Is Nothing Then%> <% End If %>
```

Using a catch-all also fails without a proper match:

```
<% If Request.QueryString("somestring") Then%> target="_blank" <% Else %> <% End If %>
```

So `www.example.com?somestring=true` works fine, however when I remove or change any part of the query string an error is thrown.

Does this method require a query string to be present? Is there a way to make this work if there is no query string and a string that doesn't match?

Any help with this would be amazing. Thank you :)

Comment: Can I ask why you're using scriptlets instead of code-behind?

Comment: I'm a designer not a developer.

Comment: Unless Request.QueryString("somestring") returns a boolean it's going to fail.  You don't get the same conversion to boolean from all types you do in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to display `target="_blank"` if `somestring` query string has a value, then this would work:

```
<% If Request.QueryString("somestring") IsNot Nothing Then%> target="_blank" <% Else %> <% End If %>
```

If you want to compare the query string to a specific value, let's say `JS`:

```
<% If Request.QueryString("somestring") = "JS" Then%> target="_blank" <% Else %> <% End If %>
```

Comment: The above code will go to the `Else` block if there's no querystring. Can you give some examples that make it errors?

Comment: Yeah that part works but if I try and then match to a specific querystring as well (like JS) it fails, hard. So IF this exact string, do this, ELSE IF not this exact string or has no string, do this.

Comment: See my edited answer, I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Smashed it! If the querystring is 'somestring=' (with trailing '=') it fails silently but that's fine! Thanks very much